# Using $(document).scrollTop() for pixels count but in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently studying JS, and in one of my projects, I want to create a fadeOut Navbar. I've played around with some code and I've found out that i need to know the number of pixels that the document is scrolled. But I've found only the answer for jQuery. I've found this code:  **$(document).scrollTop();**
But I don't really know how to convert it in Vanilla JS. Could someone please help me or give me an advice of how to get the count of the pixels or same result scrolled in the document and store it in a variable? Thank you.

HTML

```
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class = "main-container">
    <div class = "child-container-bg" >
      <h3>Hello</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    height: 4000px;
}

.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.child-container-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {

 let navBarFade = document.querySelector(".child-container-bg");
        
 var fireHeader = function (noAnimate) {
    let brkPoint  = 400;
    let fadeLength = 300;
    let opacity;
    const scrollTop  = $(document).scrollTop(); //This is the part that I can't find to change in Javascript from jQuery. I've only found the jQuery version.
            
        if (scrollTop < brkPoint) {
                opacity = 0;
        } else if (scrollTop > brkPoint + fadeLength) {
                opacity = 1;
          } else {
                    if (noAnimate) {
                            opacity = 1;
                    } else {
                            opacity = (scrollTop - brkPoint) / fadeLength;
                }
            }
            
            navBarFade.style.opacity = opacity;
            
        };
    
        fireHeader(true);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', fireHeader())
    
});
```

Comment: Do you just want the count of the pixels height or how much it has scroll? I can give a calculation for that but it's pointless because the user can still scroll even if at top of the page. Of course, the page won't move further anymore but the scroll event is still happening. Can you provide what you have so far?

Comment: What I’m searching for is to write some code that by scrolling, fades the navbar out and at the same time fades another one in. I don’t know, and maybe my approach isn’t right but I wanted to track how much the user is scrolling down from the top so that the old navbar can fade out and the new one can fade in.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you have so far, something like this will work

```js
let currentScroll = 0;
let navbarHeight = 40;

window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
    currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop
    if (currentScroll > navbarHeight) {
        // logic to remove navbar
    }
})
```

Comment: I will add now the code that I wrote and works like this, but I want to change that part I've asked above.. Thank you for your answer..